# Custom resource group name for each resource (POD/Service/Deployment/etc) in Kubernetes on AKS?

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

My Kubernetes on AKS is using one resource group to inform their costs.

At this moment we have many projects in the company, will be great if each POD report their costs to a different resource group named as the project.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to implement an intra-cluster cost tool.

The most popular in the kubernetes ecosystem is kubecost, and they have recently release and OSS version, OpenCost. https://www.opencost.io/

Typically you'd create a namespace for each app/costcentre. The default dashboards show breakdown by namespace cost over a time period.